# How to populate a div element with a dynamic html page from server in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How to populate a div element with a dynamic html page from server.

I want to implement a preview functionality in which entire page with css and sample content (rendered from server).

I tried property binding innerHtml="myDynamicPage" but it renders css part as text.
I also tried string interpolation but populates div with static string of html

Any help will appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need dynamic component. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#!#dynamic-loading

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it may resolve my Issue

Comment: Or you can create inline css if css piece is not that large to maintain. Or create a css file for all your dynamic content, load it when parent component is loaded. Ugly but simple.

Comment: Separate the text from css. Add css like $('head').append("<style>...</style>"); and after that add text as innerHtml.

Comment: if it's a preview of an entire page, you might just have to use an `iframe`...